# Intercept MudBlazor Data-grid filters and store them in local settings

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am using mudblazor 6.10.0. I have a MudDataGrid and everything works fine but i would like to store the filters in a users local settings is there a way to pick up an event when a filter is selected on a grid?

```
 <MudDataGrid T="Range" MultiSelection="true" Filterable ="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Items="@_carRanges" SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" Dense ="true"
             QuickFilter="@QuickFilter" ColumnResizeMode="@(ResizeMode.Column)" DragDropColumnReordering="true" Striped="true" FilterMode="DataGridFilterMode.ColumnFilterRow">
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudTooltip Text="Add Range">
                <MudFab id="Add-CarRange" Color="Color.Tertiary" Size="Size.Medium" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Add" Href="feerangesave/0" />
            </MudTooltip>
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="SearchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
        </ToolBarContent>
        <Columns>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" Title="name" Resizable="true" Filterable="true" />

            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.MinRange" Title="Min Range" Resizable="true" Filterable="true" Format="N0" CellStyle="text-align: right"/>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.MaxRange" Title="Max Range" Resizable="true" Filterable="true" Format="N0" CellStyle="text-align: right"/>
        </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
```